# How to use ES6 lib in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a library written in ES6/JSX and want to install it using `npm install` on a `create-react-app` application. How can I force babel to parse this lib from `node_modules`?

Something like not ignore `node_modules/my-library` when transpiling.

Comment: So you want to add a plugin/preset to Babel?

Comment: Right now I have this lib with a `package.json` file, some `.jsx`, some `.css` and some `.png` files and use it as a git submodule inside my application `src` path. I want to refer to this lib directly from `node_modules` so that I can import from "my-library", not from "../../my-library" and have it installed when someone types `npm install` without the pain of remembering the "--recursive" on git.

Answer (score 1):

I think your library shouldn't rely on third applications dependencies,
then it won't be useful and it will only work on projects that contain `Babel` as a depency.

Instead, You should add `Babel` to your library dependencies, and create a build of your library using `babel` to transpile your `ES6` code to `ES5` code which will result in standard javascript.

Therefore, you can easily add it to any project by importing the build.

Comment: I already do this for a pure algorithm library. However, for this one, I need to include the assets (styles, images, fonts...) on the build. The `babel src --out-dir dist` command will only do the work for js files.

Comment: exactly, then that library shouldn't be a library, it should be part of your project instead since you need to different stuff during the build phase

Comment: but, can you show us that library? so we can see what is your library trying to do :)

Comment: I call it library because it will be a set of components that will be used by many applications with good version control. As you wish, [here](https://github.com/wregis/react-sample-lib) you can find a sample working fine as a git submodule.

Comment: @Wanderson take a look at this article, which explains in detail what you are trying to achieve.    http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/distributing-react-components-babel-browserify-webpack-uglifyjs